# How to map a list of complex elements based on a condition on complex child element's attribute using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, parent-child

I have an xml file with below structure with many repetitive elements

Updated: In the input xml, only those elements are provided that can cause changes to mapping

```
    <offerList>
   <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
   <offer>
      <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
      <productList minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
         <listType>1</listType>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <productCategory minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
            <controlType>11</controlType>
            <product minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
               <productKey>111</productKey>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="false" picked="true" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1111</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="true" picked="true" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1112</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
            </product>
            <product minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
               <productKey>112</productKey>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="true" picked="true" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1121</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="false" picked="true" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1122</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="true" picked="false" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1123</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="false" picked="false" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1124</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
            </product>
         </productCategory>
         <productCategory minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
            <controlType>12</controlType>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <product minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
               <productKey>121</productKey>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="false" picked="true" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1211</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="false" picked="true" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1212</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
            </product>
         </productCategory>
         <productCategory minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
            <controlType>13</controlType>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <product minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
               <productKey>131</productKey>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="true" picked="true" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1311</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="false" picked="true" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1312</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
            </product>
         </productCategory>
      </productList>
   </offer>
</offerList>
```

I wanted to extract all the productCategory elements where the attributes of

```
productOption
```

with the Xpath

```
offerList/offer/productList/productCategory/product/productOption
```

and the condition is

```
either rulePicked is true or picked is false
```

The XSLT i tried creating is :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
          <xsl:variable name="ListOfCategory">
             <xsl:for-each select="offerList/offer">
                <xsl:for-each select="./productList">
                   <xsl:for-each select="./productCategory">
                      <xsl:for-each select="./product">
                         <xsl:for-each select="./productOption">
                            <xsl:if test="(./@rulePicked = true) or (./@picked = false)">
                               <xsl:copy-of select="../../../"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                         </xsl:for-each>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                   </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
             </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:variable>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

this XSLT is creating one productCategory element for each productOption satisfying the condition.

But i want the productCategory element with all the productOptions satisfying condition in it. and all other productOprions in that ProductCategory have to be removed.

The output i want should be some thing like this for the input i have given:

```
<offerList>
   <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
   <offer>
      <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
      <productList minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
         <listType>1</listType>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <productCategory minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
            <controlType>11</controlType>
            <product minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
               <productKey>111</productKey>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="true" picked="true" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1112</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
            </product>
            <product minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
               <productKey>112</productKey>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="true" picked="true" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1121</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="true" picked="false" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1123</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="false" picked="false" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1124</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
            </product>
         </productCategory>
         <productCategory minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
            <controlType>13</controlType>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <product minQuantity="0" maxQuantity="1">
               <productKey>131</productKey>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <productOption disable="?" rulePicked="true" picked="true" defaultSelection="?" requireValidation="?">
                  <optionKeyType>1311</optionKeyType>
               </productOption>
            </product>
         </productCategory>
      </productList>
   </offer>
</offerList>
```

Can any one help me in getting this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "*But i want the productCategory element with all the productOptions satisfying condition in it. and all other productOprions in that ProductCategory have to be removed.*" An example of input and the expected output would be helpful in understanding this, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edited in response to clarification:***

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="offer[not(productList/productCategory/product/productOption[@rulePicked='true' or @picked='false'])]"/>
<xsl:template match="productList[not(productCategory/product/productOption[@rulePicked='true' or @picked='false'])]"/>
<xsl:template match="productCategory[not(product/productOption[@rulePicked='true' or @picked='false'])]"/>
<xsl:template match="product[not(productOption[@rulePicked='true' or @picked='false'])]"/>
<xsl:template match="productOption[not(@rulePicked='true' or @picked='false')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This copies everything in your input *as is*, except:

- any `productOption` that does not satisfy the condition;
- any `product` that does not have at least one `productOption` child that satisfies the condition;
- any `productCategory` that does not have at least one `productOption` descendant that satisfies the condition;
- any `productList` that does not have at least one `productOption` descendant that satisfies the condition;
- any `offer` that does not have at least one `productOption` descendant that satisfies the condition.

Comment: Can i further process the output here?
Such as looping over individual offer elements and map it to a different structure?

Comment: "*Can i further process the output here?*" Yes, you can. Just add a template matching the element you want to process, and write out the expected output. -- P.S. It's not useful to think in terms of *looping* here.